# How to change the top left margin of Jquery dynatree?

Tags: jquery, jsp, dynatree, jquery-dynatree

In the ui.dynatree.js, what is the property/value that needs to be changed for the tree to appear at top left corner of the page? i.e. there should be no left and right margin. I am unable to find that one value that needs to changed. Can anyone please help.

Comment: i am not sure but you can inspect the elements using firebug,it might be  `ul.dynatree-container` change the values inside this element and check.

Answer (score 0):

This should move the tree container to an absolute position:

```
<html>
<head>
    [...]

<style type="text/css">
#tree {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 100px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#tree").dynatree({
        [...]
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
    [...]
    <div id="tree"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```